# How to eliminate the horizontal line when a range is set for a histogram in Julia Plots

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am using Julia plots to construct a histogram. A pseudo code is given:

```
data = some data
b_range = range(0, 1, length=10)
histogram!(data, bins=b_range, normalize=:probability)
```

But I have a horizontal line above the x-axis. How can I eliminate it?
[image]

Comment: The black line at the bottom is basically your data bins, more specific the bar lines. With `lines=false` they become smaller. Try e.g. `histogram(data, normalize=:probability, lines=false)`